# Decoding binary stream using Java

Tags: java, binary, protocols, decode, encode

Is there an existing mechanism to decode and encode binary data in Java from-to data container classes. Have to conform to an existing protocol over serial and network links. As it is a legacy system, the remote-end cannot be modified, and as such cannot modify the protocol headers or encapsulate the data.

From reading up on popular protocol encoders-decoders such as asn.1, protobuf, etc., it seems that they insert the data-type within the stream, i.e. modifying the raw data that is actually transmitted. This keeps them off-limits for my purpose, as they require support for the encoding-deconding format on both ends of the stream.

Comment: I am afraid we are going to need more details

Comment: It sounds like you're asking for Jackson or JAXB, but for datagrams.

Comment: You are most likely looking for the `DataInputStream`and `DataOutputStream` classes, but without more information it is impossible to be sure.

Comment: Here's more detail as to what I require. Though the actual protocol header is more complex, and there are a lot more messages, this is just a sample. Example format: <header><data type><data><crc>. My container class would be TypeA {int header, int type, int data, int crc}. I want that when the particular message arrives, it automatically populates the associated data-type container.